# Orchard 1.6 Content Type Field problems?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Orchard version is 1.6.

I created a new Content Type named **Book**, and added some Fields to this type.

I have 3 questions about fields in content type.

- What is the **difference between Input Field and Text Field**?
- How to **bind Enumeration Field with data**, for example, I want to create a Enumeration Field with data "Beijing", "Shanghai", "Guangzhou"?
- I have uploaded a .docx file with Media Picker Field writing alternative text is **This is my first attachment**, but **MediaPickerField** link is displayed in webpage, not my written alternative text. How to solve it?

That is all. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Question 3 solved! My method is to change field display name, from "Media Picker Field" to "Attachment Download link"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great questions... The difference between input field and text field is that input field should not exist. :) I was strongly against it, because it would cause confusion, and it does... The input field is supposed to help you use the new html5 input types. The text field is about entering all flavors of text. One is surfacing an implementation detail, something specific to the rendering technology used, the other is about content semantics.

Not sure what you mean with the second question. What prevents you from doing that? The values are entered in the content type editor, in the settings that appear if you deploy the field (the little > next to it).

Side note: probably would have been best to create three different questions...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Second qunestion is solved. I did not find the little > label can be clicked. I always clicked the edit button on the right of enumeration field. Thank you @Bertrand Le Roy! Orchard CMS is a great product.